# Scrapy/Python: wait for a yield request to finish before executing code (images dl)

Tags: python, scrapy, yield

I have a project where the purpose is to scrape all the chapters of a book (*parse*) then for each chapter, download the image (*parse_chapter*) and create a pdf for the chapter(*create_pdf*).

Here is my code (minimal working example) :

```
def parse(self, response):        
        chapters = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/ul/li[1]/h5/a/@href')

        for chapter in chapters:
            yield scrapy.Request(chapter.get(), callback=self.parse_chapter)
    
def parse_chapter(self, response):
        logging.debug("parse_chapter")

        image_urls = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/img/@src').get()

        yield {
            'image_urls' : image_urls
        }
        
        self.create_pdf()
        # once the pdf is created => delete all the pictures


def create_pdf(self):
        files = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + '/tmp/')
        if len(files) > 0:
            ...
```

In addition, I already modified the settings.py and pipelines.py

**The problem is :**
the function *create_pdf* is called before all the pictures are downloaded. Is there a way to wait that the yield request is over before executing *create_pdf* ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can use `callback` to the same function, so instead of creating `parse_chapter`, you just repeat the code under `parse`. Instead of running a `scrapy.Request` you can run `scrapy.follow` to follow the links under parse.

Something:

```
def parse(self, response):        
        chapters = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/ul/li[1]/h5/a/@href')

        for chapter in chapters:
            yield scrapy.follow(chapter.get(), callback=self.parse)
    
        image_urls = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/img/@src').get()
        yield {
            'image_urls' : image_urls
        }
        self.create_pdf()
        # once the pdf is created => delete all the pictures

def create_pdf(self):
        files = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + '/tmp/')
        if len(files) > 0:
            ...
```